# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.setWindowProc(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, unsatisfiedlinkerror, texturepacker

While im trying to run TexturePacker gui jar file from command line, its showing this error. Please see the image below. Thank you for your help in advance.

[image: TexturePacker JAR error]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can give you a specific solution, but the general diagnosis is that you have called a `native` method for which the the JVM hasn't been given an implementation.  Possible causes are:

- missing native libraries (DLLs, whatever)
- the JVM can't find the native libraries
- the application hasn't told the JVM to load the library (e.g. by calling `System.loadLibrary(...)`
- the library doesn't define the required native method with specific method signature that you are looking for.

In the example you have shown us, the JVM is failing to find the native code implementation for a method with this signature:

```
  void setWindowProc(java.lang.reflect.Method)
```

that is declared in the class `org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay`.  The problem could be a missing or incorrectly configured library, or it could be due to a version mismatch between the library's DLL and Java code.

Based on a 2 minute read of the "getting started" example for LWJGL, it doesn't look like there is an explicit initialization call that your application needs to make.  (But I may have missed something, or you may be using a version of the library that doesn't match the "getting started" docs.)